# Ansible - set var with condition

Tags: ansible

I'm traying to set a value for a prompt variable with the next code:

```
- name: "test"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: yes

  vars_prompt:

    - name: https
      prompt: Use https(yes/NO)?
      private: no
      default: no

  vars:
    protocol: "{{ 'https' if https else 'http' }}" 

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ https | bool }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ protocol }}"
```

The result is allways https.. why?

```
Use https(yes/NO)? [False]: no

PLAY [test] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": false
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "https"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I have read a lot of questions here, and the correct way to do this is defining the conditional variable like I'm doing... I really don't know if there is any problem to do it with a prompted variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question... The correct way to do this is to use " | bool":

```
- name: "test"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: yes

  vars_prompt:

    - name: https
      prompt: Use https(yes/NO)?
      private: no
      default: no

  vars:
    protocol: "{{ 'https' if (https | bool) else 'http' }}" 

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ https | bool }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ protocol }}"
```